# An algorithm for detecting upside-down text along a curve.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have text along curved paths, but some of them are upside down because of the text always draws from the first point to the last point of a path.

[image]

For each path I have coordinates for them like this:

```
path1: [(X1,Y1), (X2,Y2),..., (Xn,Yn)]
path2: [(X1,Y1), (X2,Y2),..., (Xn,Yn)]
...
```

I want to find an algorithm that will solve to detect the path with upside down text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you always keep the same font size and start your text at whatever is defined as $(x_1,y_1)$ or "beginning" of the road.  Since the second point is $(x_2,y_2)$ you can simply check the sign of 
$$
x_2 - x_1
$$
If it is positive then you write normally since the road is moving to the right.  If it is negative, then the road is moving to the left and you should write upside-down.

It may be safer to use several points near the start (and take the mode sign) or to do something like $x_{10} - x_{1}$.  This will cover the bizarre cases where your data doubles back on itself or in the case where machine precision plays tricks.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!